# Не получается переделать jquery код, в чистый JS

Tags: javascript

Есть такой код для табов

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
  <title>Untitled</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style type="text/css">
   div p {
     display:  none;
   }

  </style>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script>
$(function() {
var div = $('div');
div.on('click', 'a', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
var parent = $(this).parent();
$('p',parent).show();
div.not(parent).find('p').hide()
})

});
  </script>
</head>

<body>
<!--первый элемент-->
<div>
<a href="#">link-1</a>
<p>text</p>
</div>
<!--второй элемент-->
<div>
<a href="#">link-2</a>
<p>text</p>
</div>
<!--третий элемент-->
<div>
<a href="#">link-3</a>
<p>text</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Я пытаюсь его переделать на чистый JS, но не получается.
Почему при повторном клике, таб не закрывается?

```
var div2 = document.querySelectorAll('div');

    for(var i = 0; i < div2.length; i++){

        div2[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();

          if(event.target.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'none'){
             event.target.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'block'
          }

          else if(event.target.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'block'){
             div2[i].lastElementChild.style.display = 'none'
          }


        })

        //div2[i].lastElementChild.style.display = 'none'
    }
```

Comment: а  в чем причина отказа от jQuery, если не секрет?

Comment: по сабжу в jquery у вас обработчик вешается на клик ссылки, и скрывает тэги `p`, и что-то я не особо вижу это в вашем JS коде.

Comment: Если я буду пользоваться готовыми решениями,  то так ничему не научусь

Answer (score 0):

```js
var div2 = document.querySelectorAll('div p');
var div_a = document.querySelectorAll('div a');

cloaseall(null)

function cloaseall(item) {
  div2.forEach(function(el) {
    el.classList.add("noactive")
  })
  if (item) {
    item.parentNode.children[1].classList.remove("noactive");
  }
}


for (var i = 0; i < div_a.length; i++) {
  div_a[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    cloaseall(this);
  })
}
```

```css
.noactive {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!--первый элемент-->
<div>
  <a href="#">link-1</a>
  <p>text</p>
</div>
<!--второй элемент-->
<div>
  <a href="#">link-2</a>
  <p>text</p>
</div>
<!--третий элемент-->
<div>
  <a href="#">link-3</a>
  <p>text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: А что такое cloaseall? гугл на русском ничего не выдаёт

Comment: потому что это я сейчас предумал.... ))))

Comment: Я понял это запуск функции

Comment: да. в начале все должны быть закрыты, я так понял...